# Possible to disable LSI oscillator on ARM Cortex M3 for low power stop mode?

Tags: arm, cortex-m

I am trying to add the 'independent watchdog' functionality to a project.  It works fine but I am putting the chip to sleep for extended periods to conserve the battery and the watchdog still wakes everything up and forces a reset.  Is there any way to disable the low speed internal oscillator?  I haven't been able to find any info on that.

Thanks

Comment: What is the make or model of your MCU? There are many different Cortex M3 MCUs on the market, and the watchdog is device specific.

Comment: Thanks for making me realize it was vendor specific.  That lead me to the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the ST Micro stm32f103v8 cortex M3.  It turns out with this device it is impossible to disable the independent watchdog or disable the LSI oscillator once the watchdog has been enabled.  Since the max watchdog time is about 37 seconds the current solution seems to be to wakeup every 25 seconds (to account for oscillator temperature speed differences) and reload the counter before going back to sleep.  I am going to do a power analysis on this in the next couple weeks and see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the System window watchdog (WWDG) instead of the Independent watchdog (IWDG). The WWDG will be halted when you go into sleep/stop since you stop the APB clock (PCLK)